# Is there anybody to explain how does this code actually work?(PROLOG)

Tags: prolog

So, the story began with counting the number of elements inside a list.

Then, I encountered this code when I searched for the solutions in Internet.

```
count([],0).                 
count([_HEAD|TAIL],X) :-          
   count(TAIL,X1),
   X is X1+1.
```

However, there was no clear explanation on how the code actually worked and that is why I ask here in order to get a clear explanation about this code.

Hope that someone can explain step by step so that I can understand better.

Comment: to understand prolog code, `trace` might help. also, think declarative. The predicate is recursing.

Comment: I am totally new to PROLOG and that's why I do not know that I can trace it.

Comment: As a side note, try to read about the use of accumulators and tail recursion for efficient recursive definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Please think declaratively. You are relating a list to its length, so a better, relational name would be `list_length/2`: The first argument is a list, the second its length.

Obviously, the length of the empty list `[]` is 0.

Further, if `Tail` is a list of length `L0`, then the length of `[_|Tail]` is the number `L0 + 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder and next time I will use a better name.

Comment: @user3310635: mat's point is rather the last sentence: Reading right-to-left in the direction of the arrow `:-`

Comment: Sorry because I ignored the last part. I think this situation only applicable when there is only en element in a list,right? This is because if there is nothing in a list, then it will match count([],0) and hence I will get 0 as return value.

Answer (score 2):

`count([] ,0)` means that an empty list has 0 element.
Now, to count the elements of a list

```
count([_HEAD|TAIL],X):-       
    % we remove the first element of the list
    % we count the elements of the rest of the list
    count(TAIL,X1),
    % and we add 1 to the number of the elements of the rest
    X is X1+1.
```

Comment: Hello, do you mean that if I have something like this, for example count([a,b,c,d,e,f],X).

Comment: (Please ignore the above comment)Hello, do you mean that if I have something like this, for example count([a,b,c,d,e,f],X), first, when count([a,b,c,d,e,f],X) encounters count([_HEAD|TAIL],X), 'a' will be eliminated. Then, after 'a' is eliminated, now the tail is [b,c,d,e,f] but now it encounters count(TAIL,X1). So, since there is a total of 5 remaining elements, X1 is 5 and X is now becoming 6 and then 6 is returned. Please point out if the real situation does not look like this.

Comment: @user3310635: This explanation assumes that you have a list, for there would be no point of removing, if there is no list. But then, you can say `count(L,2)`.

Comment: But I still not very sure that how does it know there are how many elements inside TAIL. For example, as what I stated just now, " now the tail is [b,c,d,e,f] but now it encounters count(TAIL,X1). So, since there is a total of 5 remaining elements, X1 is 5 ". Actually I want to know that why X1 will be 5 because I do not think that it will automatically count how many elements in TAIL and for surely, there must be a process behind this and I would like to know more about this process.

Comment: @false:Could you spend a little time to demonstrate why I can say count(L,2)?Sorry because I really cannot get what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Learning to think recursively is hard. Most recursive problems can be broken down into a few "special cases" and the general case. In this case, we have two cases:

- **the empty list.** This is our **special case**. The length of the empty list is ALWAYS zero.
- **A non-empty list.** This is our **general case**.We have the list's *head* (a single item) and its *tail* (the remainder of the list: zero or more items). So, we can say that the length of a non-empty list is the length of its *tail*, plus 1 (the *head*).

Prolog lets you simply *declare* these to be facts defining *truth*. Then we let the Prolog inference engine determine the truth or falsity of an assertion. To whit:

```
count( []     , 0 ) .  % The count of an empty list is zero
count( [_|Xs] , N ) :- % If the list is non-empty, 
  count( Xs, T ) ,     % - we count its tail as T
  N is T+1             % - and then add 1.
  .                    %
```

Then... you can say things like:

```
?- count([],3).
false.

?- count([a,b,c],3).
true.
```

This also works in a *generative* manner:

```
?- count( List , 3 ) .
List = [_G938, _G941, _G944] .
```

Or even...

```
?- count(X,N).
X = [], N = 0 ;
X = [_G950], N = 1 ;
X = [_G950, _G953], N = 2 ;
X = [_G950, _G953, _G956], N = 3 ;
...
```

Note that this is not tail-recursive and feed a list of sufficient length, will eventually overflow its stack.

You can write it in a tail-recursive manner as well, which might be easier to understand:

```
count( Xs , N ) :-    % to count the number of items in a list,
  count( Xs , 0 , N ) % - invoke the helper, seeding the accumulator with 0.
  .                   %

count( []     , N , N ) .  % if the source list is empty, the accumulator contains the number of items in the list.
count( [_|Xs] , T , N ) :- % otherwise (source list is non-empty)
  T1 is T+1 ,              % - increment the accumulator, and
  count(Xs,T1,N)           % - recurse down on the tail, passing the incremented accumulator
  .                        %
```

Comment: Yes, I found this is easier to understand if compared to the one I posted earlier. I really appreciate for this answer but I think if I understand both then it will be better.